# JPA/JPQL JOIN Subselect/Subquery

Tags: java, jpa, join, subquery, jpql

I have trouble to translate some easy SQL statement to JPQL, because of a used subquery, which is not supported by JPQL.

Can someone give me a hint, how to achieve the same result with JPQL or JPA2 Criteria API?

Given (Simplified fake data to demonstrate the problem):

```
CREATE TABLE person (id integer, name text);
CREATE TABLE phone (id integer, person_id integer, type text, number text);

INSERT INTO person VALUES (1, "John");
INSERT INTO person VALUES (2, "Mike");
INSERT INTO person VALUES (3, "Paul");
INSERT INTO person VALUES (4, "Walter");

INSERT INTO phone VALUES (1, 1, "MOBILE", "+49-123-11111");
INSERT INTO phone VALUES (2, 1, "HOME"  , "+49-123-22222");
INSERT INTO phone VALUES (3, 2, "WORK"  , "+49-123-33333");
INSERT INTO phone VALUES (4, 4, "MOBILE", "+49-123-44444");

-- Select all from person and their mobile number if possible
-- This query has to be translated to JPQL

SELECT person.name, mobile.number FROM person LEFT JOIN (
  SELECT * FROM phone WHERE type = "MOBILE"
) AS mobile ON person.id = mobile.person_id;
```

Expected result:

```
| name   | number        |
|--------|---------------|
| John   | +49-123-11111 |
| Mike   |               |
| Paul   |               |
| Walter | +49-123-44444 |
```

Java:

```
class Person {
    String name;
    List<Phone> phones;
}

class Phone {
    String type;
    String number;
}
```

JPQL (not working as expected :-( ):

```
SELECT person.name, phone.number FROM Person person
    LEFT JOIN person.phones AS phone
    WHERE phone.type = "MOBILE"
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
SELECT person.name, phone.number 
   FROM Person AS person LEFT JOIN person.phones AS phone 
   ON phone.type = 'MOBILE'
```

You can also replace the `ON` keyword with the hibernate specific `WITH`:

```
SELECT person.name, phone.number 
   FROM Person AS person LEFT JOIN person.phones AS phone 
   WITH phone.type = 'MOBILE'
```

Answer (score 1):

First of all according to the [Java Persistence Wikibook](https://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/Java_Persistence/JPQL#Sub-selects_in_FROM_clause) some JPA providers like *EclipseLink* and *TopLink* support sub selects in the `FROM` clause - although this is not defined in the JPA spec.

In JPA 2.1 you could use `LEFT JOIN` with `ON`:

```
SELECT person.name, phone.number
FROM Person person
LEFT JOIN person.phones AS phone ON phone.person = person AND phone.type = 'MOBILE'
```

Before JPA 2.1 you could use a `case` expression:

```
SELECT person.name, 
  CASE WHEN (phone.type = 'MOBILE') THEN phone.number ELSE '' END 
FROM Person person
LEFT JOIN person.phones AS phone
```

But this will just wipe all *none-mobile* phone numbers - so there will be a row for each phone number of a person, even if he/she has more than one phone number that is not a mobile number.

You could use the *list aggregation* function of your database (like `LISTAGG` in Oracle), if your JPA provider renders these correctly (Hibernate does in most circumstances). This would make sense for the first two options as well - if a person can have more than one mobile number.

Answer (score -1):

Try this:

```sql
   SELECT person.name, phone.number 
     FROM Person person
LEFT JOIN person.phones AS phone
    WHERE phone.type IS NULL OR phone.type = "MOBILE"
```

Comment: This will not work too. The WHERE clause removes rows after joining the phone table. So Mike, who only has a WORK number, will be dropped.